Springboot scheduled application increasing memory in docker
I have a springboot microservice (updated to spring-boot-starter-parent 3.4.0) that is run on a schedule every 5 minutes that checks a database table (oracle jdbc driver 19.20.0.0) for new task entries to process.  The docker container has 2G memory limit set. The scheduler class is as follows
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class CreateBundleScheduler {
    protected final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CreateBundleScheduler.class);
    
    private final CreateBundleTaskDAO createBundleTaskDao;

    private final CopyBundleTaskDAO copyBundleTaskDao;

    @Autowired
    public CreateBundleScheduler(CreateBundleTaskDAO createBundleTaskDao,
                                 CopyBundleTaskDAO copyBundleTaskDao) {
        this.createBundleTaskDao = createBundleTaskDao;
        this.copyBundleTaskDao = copyBundleTaskDao;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${schedule.fixed.delay.in.milliseconds}")
    public void schedule() {
        LOGGER.info("Create Bundle scheduler start at {}", ZonedDateTime.now());

        //Get list of tasks that need to be created
        List<CreateBundleTask> tasks = createBundleTaskDao.findFirstByStatusOrderByCreatedDateAsc(TaskStatus.SUBMITTED, PageRequest.of(0, 1));

        tasks.stream().forEach(task -> {
            LOGGER.info("Starting bundle creation for task {} ", task.getTaskId());
        });

        //Get list of tasks that need to be copied - one at a time because they are usually big bundles
        List<CopyBundleTask> copyTasks = copyBundleTaskDao.findFirstByStatusOrderByCreatedDateAsc(TaskStatus.SUBMITTED);

        copyTasks.stream().forEach(task -> {
            LOGGER.info("Starting bundle copy for task {} ", task.getTaskId());
        });
    }

}

@Repository
public interface CreateBundleTaskDAO extends JpaRepository<CreateBundleTask, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT t FROM CreateBundleTask t WHERE t.status = :status ORDER BY t.createdDate ASC")
    List<CreateBundleTask> findFirstByStatusOrderByCreatedDateAsc(TaskStatus status, Pageable pageable);
}

similar for CopyBundleTaskDAO

I have been running this on my local docker machine changing the interval to 2 seconds, and there are always ZERO tasks to process. However the memory usage has been creeping up slowly.
First it started off at 420MB -> 2 hours later it is now at 471MB.  I hit the healthcheck endpoint (springboot actuator) a few times too but mostly its just the scheduler running.
I have taken a heap dump and used the Eclipse Memory Analyzer tool to help me detect leaks
Below are the screenshots - most of them are saying that the problem is org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.LaunchedClassLoader - I am not sure how to fix this or am I looking at the wrong thing?
Thanks in advance!



EDIT: server snapshots
Dec 2nd:

Dec 11th:


And it is a problem because? GC will only kick in if it needs to, there is still enough free memory so no GC has happend yet.

I have turned on the GC logs and I see it running - even when it cleans up the old regions the memory never seems to recover some? Its a problem because the memory keeps going up and up and with multiple docker instances that do this on a container we fill up the memory.

Edit: going to add the screenshots from the server - they are 9 days apart and the memory has just been growing especially for the top 3 containers which is the @scheduled springboot app as described above.

That is not what you mentioned in your initial question. If I where you I would ditch the @Query as the method as is with the name should be enough. Spring Data appears to be recreating the query, also why a list if you only retrieve 1? I also doubt that this is your actual method (as it doesn't do anything) so there is more that will occupy memory (and generally that is due to bad transaction management or leaking sessions, connections).

Yes I removed the code from the snippet because when I was debugging localhost it actually doesnt reach the other code.
It didn't have @Query before but I saw the antlr library was in the MAT so thought maybe if it didnt have to parse the method name it might make a difference?  Clutching at straws really.
Thanks for your help anyway.

The point with the query is that it needs to be parsed each time due to the passing of the Pageable so it will create a new fresh query each time. Which isn't needed if it parses the method at least it should re-use it.
